# Third tab panel is not accessible in Ajax tab container

Tags: asp.net, ajax, containers, tabs

I have an ajax tab container in an aspx page. Earlier I had 2 tab panels in the tab cotnainer. Now I want to add third tab panel. I could add the third panel but I am able to access the third panel, i.e. When I click on third panel, the panel is not shown(I didnt even get the handy cursor when i place the cursor on the third tab panel name).

Can anyone tell me the reason for this and the way to access the third tab.

Thanks,
Rupa

Comment: With out code how can one quest whats the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

after 'UL', you need to put the ID of the tab in a 'DIV', when not using AJAX, ex.

```
<div id="ui-tab-3">my tab content</div>
```